# Remove spacing from lists in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe with lists of strings and I need to remove the whitespace in each list:

```
ID        numbers
0      [ 1, 2,3, 4]
1      [ abc, zzy]
2      [ zz12, 22wq, 78]
```

How can I remove the spacing in the 'numbers' field?

```
ID        numbers
0      [1,2,3,4]
1      [abc,zzy]
2      [zz12,22wq,78]
```

This is what I have tried:

```
# remove spacing
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].replace({' ':''}, regex=True)
```

But it does not seem to work!

Comment: is the `numbers` column a string?

Comment: Yes all strings

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [0, 1, 2], 'numbers': [[' 1', '2','3',' 4'], [' abc',' zzy'], [' zz12',' 22wq',' 78']]})

temp = df.explode('numbers')
temp['numbers'] = temp.numbers.str.strip()
temp.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(list)

   ID           numbers
0   0      [1, 2, 3, 4]
1   1        [abc, zzy]
2   2  [zz12, 22wq, 78]
```

Please note that there will still be a space after each comma in the list as this is how the IDE formats all lists, however each string item within the list has had *all* white-space stripped from it.

Comment: I just tested this locally and it works fine if the `numbers` column is a string, as you indicated

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake. Each record is a list of characters. The entire object is not a string. Sorry about that, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

using `lambda` expression:

```
df['numbers'] = df['numbers'].apply(lambda x : [str(y).strip() for y in x])

   ID           numbers
0   0      [1, 2, 3, 4]
1   1        [abc, zzy]
2   2  [zz12, 22wq, 78]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if values are of the type "[1 ,2 ,3]" & not [1, 2, 3] i.e list:
df['numbers']=df['numbers'].transform(lambda val: str(val).replace(' ',''))

But this will make your column str type.
If you want to return the values as list, then
df['numbers']=df['numbers'].transform(lambda val: [x for x in ini_list.strip('] [').replace(',','').split(' ')])
This will return values as list elements